# where to store api key in Django

Tags: ajax, django, mongodb, mlab

I currently build web app which is using external MongoDb via Mongolabs.
The api is based on personal key using in urls. As docs says e.g.:

Here’s an example of a complete Resource URL:

https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases?apiKey=**2E81PUmPFI84t7UIc_5YdldAp1ruUPKye**
So the question is how to securely store such api key **2E81PUmPFI84t7UIc_5YdldAp1ruUPKye**

Reading Django docs about Cross Site Request Forgery but stil do not understand where the key is recorded.

Comment: Just save it in the settings.py there is no need to provide any additional security. If someone can read your source code you are in deep trouble already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

One way is to have a `local_settings.py` file that's imported in the main `settings.py` file and put into `.gitignore` so it's not in git. Some people however think this isn't good practice, because it might tempt to put complex things in there that aren't in VCS, so people effectively have different environments. I however am fine with it.

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass  # No local_settings file
```

---

The other way (recommended by dislikers of the first way) is by setting it via environment variables, and reading these in `settings.py`.

```
MONGO_API_KEY = os.environ['MONGO_API_KEY']
```

You'd then have to pass the environment variable somehow though. E.g. via uwsgi's environ setting, or by setting it in your bash with export, or via another way.

Answer (score 1):

I would load it in the settings file from an environment variable. Have a look at the [Django Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/)

Comment: Often times these API keys are meant to be kept secret, so putting it somewhere in the codebase is not ideal if your project is open source.

Comment: That's the reason why I would load it from environment variables. I never said to write them as strings into settings.py.

Comment: Ah ok. Makes sense

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use the library `django-fernet-fields` that uses the library `cryptography`.

The usage is very simple. In your model you need to add a new field:

```
from django.db import models
from fernet_fields import EncryptedTextField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    apikey = EncryptedTextField()
```

By default, the field is going to be encrypted using the `SECRET_KEY` from your settings. So if you change it or lose it, you will not be able to access your data.

For better security, you can save your `SECRET_KEY` as an environment variable, and then pass it to the settings file.

```
import os

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('APP_SECRET_KEY', 'unsafe-secret-key')
```

[django-fernet-fields](https://django-fernet-fields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

1. Store in .env
2. Read in settings.py